# Modify SQL query

Tags: sql, alter

Somewhere in my application, I have a query:

```
$sql = SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY column1;
```

I pass this query to my class, which generates a table:

```
$table = new HtmlTable($sql)
```

This $table object has a method 'groupBy', which should alter the $sql string and it should add second column in the ORDER BY clause, so the query should look like:

```
$sql = SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY added_column, column;
```

I tried this:

```
select * from (SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY column1) innerSQL ORDER BY innerSQL.column2
```

but it does not sort correctly ..

Actually, what I need is this:

```
$sql = SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY column2, column1;
```

But i don't know, how can I alter the $sql string inside the HtmlTable class ..

Any ideas?

Comment: I already tried this solution and it does not work ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a regular expression to do it. Here's an example of how your method could look like:

```
protected function groupBy($sql) {
  return preg_replace('/ORDER BY (.*)/i', 'ORDER BY SomeField, $1', $sql);
}
```

What it does is replacing "ORDER BY " with "ORDER BY , SomeField". Here's an example to test it:

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY column1';
$sql = preg_replace('/ORDER BY (.*)/i', 'ORDER BY SomeField, $1', $sql);
echo $sql;
```

Comment: This would work (assuming @Juraj has access to the guts of `HtmlTable`, which isn't clear from the question), but I think the original requirement is to add the new field first, so the replacement should be `'ORDER BY SomeField, $1'`

Comment: He wrote "_This $table object has a method 'groupBy', which should alter the $sql string_", therefore I assume that he can modify the groupBy method. You're right about the field order, I put it after by mistake. I'm correcting the answer now, thanks.